# Grafana find latency using timestamps from different log lines

Tags: grafana-loki

My log lines in Grafana looks like this,

```
2023-04-04 07:33:46,475 INFO   comms.handler.Client - Attempting to retrieve response for transaction id:S-476155
2023-04-04 07:33:46,583 INFO   comms.handler.Client - Response received for transaction id:S-476155 with return code:5003
2023-04-04 07:33:46,475 INFO   comms.handler.Client - Attempting to retrieve response for transaction id:S-476156
2023-04-04 07:33:46,475 INFO   comms.handler.Client - Attempting to retrieve response for transaction id:S-476157
```

Is there a way to group by the transaction ID in a log message and find the latency between the request and response?

Please note that I can use a query like this and get the request and response ids and the respective timestamps,

```
{app="app",environment="dev"} 
|~ "Attempting to retrieve response for transaction | Response received for transaction id" 
| regexp "(?P<time>\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3}) .* (Attempting to retrieve response for transaction id:(?P<request_id>[^ ]*)|Response received for transaction id:(?P<response_id>[^ ]*) with return code:\\d*)"
| line_format "{{.time}} {{.request_id}} {{.response_id}}"
```

That creates calculated fields like this

[image]

But I don't know if we can group by the calculated fields and plot the latency in a graph.

Any help is appreciated.